# SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-02291

I am creating a database that is trying to access values from a foreign key. I have created two following tables

```
CREATE TABLE Component(
    ComponentID varchar2(9) PRIMARY KEY
    , TypeID varchar2(9) REFERENCES TypeComponent(TypeComponentID)
)

INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359823,785404309)
INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359347,785404574)
INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359467,785404769)
INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359845,785404867)
INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359303,785404201)
INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359942,785404675)


CREATE TABLE TypeComponent (
    TypeComponentID varchar2(9) PRIMARY KEY
    , Type_Description varchar2(30) CONSTRAINT Type_Description 
        CHECK(Type_Description IN('Strap', 'Buckle', 'Stud')) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO TypeComponent VALUES(785404309, 'Strap')
INSERT INTO TypeComponent VALUES(785404574, 'Stud')
INSERT INTO TypeComponent VALUES(785404769, 'Buckle')
INSERT INTO TypeComponent VALUES(785404867, 'Strap')
INSERT INTO TypeComponent VALUES(785404201, 'Buckle')
INSERT INTO TypeComponent VALUES(785404675, 'Stud')
```

These are the two tables. `Component` and `TypeComponent`. `Component` is the parent entity to `TypeComponent`, and I am trying to run the following INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359823,785404309)
```

but it is giving me the error

This is the session that I have so far in Oracle SQL dev

Comment: Can you please post your entire session and reformat your post a little bit ?

Comment: Whenever you enter SQL statements and error logs, please select the statements and click on Code (ie, icon with `1010` so  that it is legible. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try inserting in your `TypeComponent` table first, then insert into your `Component` table.

According to the error:

> **ORA-02291:**    integrity constraint (string.string) violated - parent key not found
>   **Cause:**            A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
>   **Action:**            Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.

This means that there is no matching key in your referenced table.

**EDIT #1**

For your kind information, here is a site where you can get help with all of the Oracle error codes.

`http://[ora-02291].ora-code.com/`

Here's the homepage for this site: **http://www.ora-code.com/**

Where you may replace the error code in the URL to suit the error code you're getting, and you'll access to the page for this error.

Comment: So are you saying that I should drop the two tables, then CREATE the TypeComponent table first then insert the statement into the Component table?

Comment: Ideally, know what is dependent, and what is not. In your scenario, `Component` depends on `TypeComponent`. I like to think of it like an atomic object. It can exist by itself. On the other hand, `Component` cannot exist without `TypeComponent`, since its `TypeID` field references the primary key of the `TypeComponent` table. Hence, when inserting into `Component`, the database engine checks for the reference you're giving it, the value of the `TypeComponent.TypeComponentID`, and since it cannot find it, it rejects the insertion, otherwise you would have a data integrity concern.

Comment: I don't think the table creation order is an issue here, since you said that they both exist in your database. Aside, it would have perhaps made it obvious if you would have created the `TypeComponent` table before the `Component`, that a row needs to exist in `TypeComponent` in order to insert into `Component`.

Answer (score 3):

Please post your entire SQLPLUS session so that the error is easily reproducible.

Looks like the insert into the child table is being done before the insert into the parent table which is causing this error.

Change the order of inserts and rerun your code.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TypeComponent(
  2    TypeComponentID varchar2(9) PRIMARY KEY, 
  3    Type_Description     varchar2(30) 
  4    CONSTRAINT Type_Description CHECK(Type_Description IN('Strap', 'Buckle', 'Stud')) NOT NULL
  5  )
  6  ;

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE Component(
  2    ComponentID varchar2(9) PRIMARY KEY, 
  3    TypeID varchar2(9) REFERENCES TypeComponent(TypeComponentID)
  4  )
  5  ;

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359823,785404309);
INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359823,785404309)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (COAMGR.SYS_C002513823) violated - parent key
not found

SQL> INSERT INTO TypeComponent VALUES(785404309, 'Strap');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359823,785404309);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

In `component` table you have

```
 TypeID REFERENCES TypeComponent(TypeComponentID)
```

And then you proceed with

```
INSERT INTO Component VALUES(192359823,785404309)
```

If you executed this first, then Oracle will throw `Integrity constraint` error because you are trying to insert into `component` table a value which is not present in `TypeComponent` table.

This is a problem because you have mentioned that `TypeID` is a foreign key, ie, the value of `TypeID` needs to be present in `TypeComponent` before inserting into `Component`

Comment: Worth pointing out a general rule here: when populating data, populate the *reference* data first (so component *type* is reference data), then main data.

Answer (score 1):

This error is present some times with the referenced key (foreign key in my case) this have errors. Please recreate the referenced key in the table.