# ORA-02291: integrity constraint (INA.member#mem_id) violated - parent key not found

Tags: database, oracle, insert, key, parent

Error report - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (INA.member#mem_id) violated - parent key not found.

```
 into INA.member
(mem_id,mem_insertaddress,address_type,effective_date,end_date,adress,city,zip_code,phone_number,last_name,first_name)
values
(19889218,191166765,'Z2','01-AUG-2013','07-MAY-2016','45 NEWYORK','ATLANTIC','NY',011101,2012922341,'BOB','GUY');
```

when try to run getting error message 
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (INA.member#mem_id) violated - parent key not found.
really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349864/sql-error-ora-02291-integrity-constraint)

Comment: I have seen the similar question but the answers I am not able to understand.

Comment: i did not create the table.But trying to insert values for testing purpose.

Comment: please suggest what i have done wrong in the insert statement.

Comment: It's telling you that there is a foreign key constraint on mem_id, meaning that the value you're trying to insert there should exist in the parent table. Have a look at the DDL for the member table to find the parent table, the value you want to insert in mem_id **must** exist there. Referential integrity is a key concept of relational databases, I highly recommend reading more about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have two more tables, namely `socialClubs` and `clubMembership`, and neccessary constraints( `primary` *and* `foreign` ) defined as below :

```
SQL> create table socialClubs(   -- parent(look-up) table for "clubMembership" table.
  2                           id        int primary key,
  3                           name      varchar2(500)
  4                           ); 

Table created
SQL> create table clubMembership( -- parent table for "member" table.
  2                               id      int primary key,
  3                               club_id int,
  4                               constraint fk_cmmb_sc_id
  5                                  foreign key(club_id)
  6                               references socialClubs(id)
  7                              ); 

Table created
SQL> create table member(
  2                      mem_id         int primary key,
  3                      mem_address    varchar2(500),
  4                      address_type   varchar2(10),
  5                      effective_date date,
  6                      end_date       date,
  7                      adress         varchar2(500),
  8                      city           varchar2(50),
  9                      zip_code       varchar2(10),
 10                      phone_number   number(15),
 11                      last_name      varchar2(50),
 12                      first_name     varchar2(50),
 13                      constraint fk_cmmb_mem_id
 14                         foreign key(mem_id)
 15                      references clubMembership(id)
 16                      );

Table created
SQL> insert into socialClubs values(1,'Mathematics');

1 row inserted
SQL> insert into member
  2    (mem_id,
  3     mem_address,
  4     address_type,
  5     effective_date,
  6     end_date,
  7     adress,
  8     city,
  9     zip_code,
 10     phone_number,
 11     last_name,
 12     first_name)
 13  values
 14    (19889218,
 15     191166765,
 16     'Z2',
 17     date'2013-08-01',
 18     date'2016-05-07',
 19     '45 NEWYORK',
 20     'ATLANTIC NY',
 21     011101,
 22     2012922341,
 23     'BOB',
 24     'GUY');


ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ASKIMEMUR.FK_CMMB_MEM_ID) violated - parent key not found
```

raises *ORA-02291 error*,

since there's no (parent) record found in *clubMembership* table for *member_id* 19889218 of *member* table which has an inline definition of `constraint fk_cmmb_mem_id foreign key(mem_id) references clubMembership(id)`.

So insert the necessary member_id into *clubMembership* table and go on without problem :

```
SQL> insert into clubMembership values(19889218,1);

1 row inserted
SQL> insert into member
  2    (mem_id,
  3     mem_address,
  4     address_type,
  5     effective_date,
  6     end_date,
  7     adress,
  8     city,
  9     zip_code,
 10     phone_number,
 11     last_name,
 12     first_name)
 13  values
 14    (19889218,
 15     191166765,
 16     'Z2',
 17     date'2013-08-01',
 18     date'2016-05-07',
 19     '45 NEWYORK',
 20     'ATLANTIC NY',
 21     011101,
 22     2012922341,
 23     'BOB',
 24     'GUY');

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete
```