# ERROR:ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYS.SYS_C004198) violated - parent key not found

Tags: database

```
create table centralsupplies
(
wardnum int  references ward(wnum),
drugnum int references pharmasupplies(dnum),
quantity_required varchar(20),
staffnum int references staff(stnum),
regnum int unique,
dateord date,
daterec date,
primary key(wardnum,drugnum,staffnum)
);

insert into centralsupplies values(1,204,1000,125,300,DATE '2020-01-02',DATE '2020-01-12');

insert into centralsupplies values(2,203,980,124,301,DATE '2020-01-03',DATE '2020-01-09');

OUTPUT:insert into centralsupplies values(1,204,1000,125,300,DATE '2020-01-02',DATE '2020-01-12')
```

how do i insert this entry????

Comment: Well then you are missing rows in one or more of the parent tables that are FKs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349864/sql-error-ora-02291-integrity-constraint)